# TFS MTM 2013 Test Suite, Test Run on the basis of suite State

Tags: tfs, test-suite, mtm

Can we disable run button when Test Suite state is “In Planning” or “Completed”.
Basically we don't want the test cases to run when Test Suite state is “In Planning” or “Completed”..

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not possible. [You can set a filter on the Test Plan/Suite to not show these tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292093%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[image]

Why would you want to be unable to run the tests? Running the tests early could give you important feedback on mismatches between understanding of the specification by coders or testers. Running them when they are completed might be for additional verification or just to be sure that something hasn't changed.